# Gradle: How to configure multiproject setup with side-by-side projects

Tags: java, build, gradle, multi-project

We have an old project that is set up like this:

```
.
├── customizationProject
│   ├── ejb
│   └── services
├── projectA
│   ├── ejb
│   └── shared
├── projectB
│   └── ejb
└── projectC
    ├── ejb
    └── services
```

The idea is that the customizationProject is where the final assembly of the delivered application happends, there might in fact be multiple  `customizationProjects` and they might include multiple configurations. That, however is not the problem I'm tyring to solve.

I want to make the customizationProject the logical root project of the gradle projects.
How do I configure the individual projects, so that they
a) know they're part of a multiproject build
b) can be properly executed, with different scopes, e.g. just running the tests of one subproject, while also allowing *all* tests to be executed accross all the projects?

Comment: This project is currently built using a shaky ant script, that knows nothing about dependencies. I want to migrate it to gradle...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is a fairly easy structure to support with Gradle. Add a settings.gradle file to your customizationProject directory with this content:

```
includeFlat 'projectA', 'projectB', 'projectC'
```

And you can confirm the project structure from the command line:

```
$ gradle projects
:projects

------------------------------------------------------------
Root Project
------------------------------------------------------------

Root project 'customizationProject'
+--- Project ':projectA'
+--- Project ':projectB'
\--- Project ':projectC'
```

The description of the includeFlat method is available in the [Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings.html#org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings:includeFlat(java.lang.String%5B%5D)).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Important note: You need to run gradle in the directory `customizationProject` (where the settings.gradle file is), otherwise it won't find the projects.

Comment: Remember to add a lines for each project in your dependencies section like: compile (project(':projectA'))