# Require Gradle project from another directory

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, android-library, multi-project

I have a directory/project setup like this:

```
C:\
    _dev\
        Projects\
            Logger
            MyProject
```

*Logger* is an Android library project using Gradle. *MyProject* is a standard Android project project that needs to make use of the *Logger* library.

I am using Android Studio and have tried adding *Logger* to the external libraries. Whilst this works during development, I get messages about the class not being found when building.

I'm completely new to Gradle, but have tried the following in my build.gradle within *MyProject*:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }

    dependencies {
        compile files("../Logger")
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:18.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17479076/android-studio-add-external-project-to-build-gradle

Comment: Already tried that unfortunately.

    include ':logger'
    project(':logger').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../SysLog')

Comment: write this line ```includeFlat   'prjname'```  into MyProject\settings.gradle  . if project are sideByside / Flat / same level  , gradle auto accepts that. also it project automatically pops up in intellij idea 

details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995390/gradle-how-to-configure-multiproject-setup-with-side-by-

Comment: This question is too frequently visited by me, almost every time I make a new gradle project, so I put it in favorites.

Answer (score 206, accepted):

The simplest way is to make `MyProject` a multi project with the `Logger` project as a subproject.

`settings.gradle` in `MyProject` directory:

```
include ":logger"
project(":logger").projectDir = file("../logger")
```

In the `build.gradle` of `MyProject` you can now reference this lib as a project:

```
dependencies {
     compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:18.0.0'
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'
     compile project(":logger")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. The project compiled successfully as soon as I added this.

Comment: Can you use a property value from the Gradle home directory's gradle.properties file?

Comment: This is exactly what I just inferred I might be able to do, and so is exactly the answer I was looking for :-D

Comment: I got same situation and this solution in settings.gradle worked for me

Comment: I get an error that the project already exists, when I give it a new name it clones my repository into my workspace.

Comment: none of this hyper-over-extended build stuff makes any sense anymore. gradle is getting almost to be like autotools. Bless you for providing a simple answer and solution, and for making things work without the rest of us who just want to write software having to understand it.

Comment: Thanks, worked well, I read over here https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings.html#org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings:include(java.lang.String[]) for deeper understanding as well

Comment: I know this is ages old, but is there any way to do this iteratively for a long list of subprojects rather than statically defining them all like this?

Comment: `file('')` didn't work, but `new File('')` worked, I'm on Windows

Comment: What if that external dependencies has its own project depencies? Those paths are not resolved.

Answer (score 15):

Android Studio 2.2.3:

Add to settings.gradle.

```
include ':app', ':new_lib'
project(':new_lib').projectDir = new File('../new_lib/app')
```

- The path must be relative from the root of the project you're working
  on.
- The module you're referencing must have a reference to it's "app"
  directory.

Then edit your Project Structure | Modules to setup dependencies.

Comment: I tried this in Android Studio but now my root project is no longer considered a library and the build variants only show what you called ":new_lib" as the available module. The original 'app' is no longer in the module list.

Answer (score 10):

Try adding the dependency to the global "dependencies" section, not the "android > dependencies".
During development, the "android" configuration is used, but not to package the runtime.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:18.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'
    compile files("../Logger")
}
```

It may also be worthwhile to look into setting up a multi-project gradle configuration,
with a build.gradle and settings.gradle in the shared parent directory like here: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html

Comment: Just tried that, with no success unfortunately. Still getting the same errors.

Answer (score 2):

For those who meet the error `Could not find method compile()...` based on the answer from @Rene Groeschke, @Michael Mrozek and @user924, in the `build.gradle` of `MyProject` use

```
implementation project(":logger")
```

instead of

```
compile project(":logger")
```

It works with `Gradle-7.4`

Answer (score -2):

Here is a solution for settings.gradle.kts and build.gradle.kts ([Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html)).

settings.gradle.kts:

```kotlin
include(":my-sub-project")
```

Top-level build.gradle.kts:

```kotlin
dependencies {
    implementation(project(":my-sub-project"))
    // ...
}
```

Directory structure:

```
 project
  ├─── settings.gradle.kts
  ├─── build.gradle.kts
  ├───  my-sub-project
  │   ├─── build.gradle.kts
  │   └─── ...
  └─── ...
```

Comment: Technically correct (like Microsoft), but not what was asked for ;-)