# Gradle dependency settings confusion

Tags: gradle, dependency-management

Consider the following project structure as a **Gradle** build:

```
backend
|- adapters
   |- adapter-common
   |- bar-adapter
      |- bar-entrypoint
      |- bar-models
      \- bar-services
   \- foo-adapter
      |- foo-entrypoint
      |- foo-models
      \- foo-services
|- backend-common
|- db-conn
|- backend-entrypoint
|- build.gradle
\- settings.gradle
```

The dependency structure is as follows:
`foo-adapter` depends on `foo-entrypoint` and `adapter-common`
`foo-entrypoint` depends on `foo-services`
`foo-services` depends on `foo-models`
`adapter-common` depends on `backend-common` & `db-conn`

Now I have a separate project `api` where I need `foo-adapter` as a dependency. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299316/require-gradle-project-from-another-directory) Q&A which seems to be the same situation but when I tried it I get errors about how none of the other projects (`adapter-common`, `db-conn`, etc.) are found.

Am I asking too much from **Gradle** by telling it to just import `foo-adapter` and then expecting it to pull in and resolve all the dependencies itself?

Is there any way to get this to work without declaring basically the whole `backend` project in my `api` settings file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your foo-adapter project use some classes from other projects it cannot be added without the others. Not matters it's a jar or just uncompiled stuff. You need the others too. It's a really bad approach to depend a project on another. Better you use only interfaces and put them into a separate project. Thus your projects can be compiled independently and you need just one configuration project that combines all that stuff.