# Create a dependency on gradle projects

Tags: java, gradle

[Referred this link](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html)

I have about 8 projects that I need to build is a particular order to finally build my rest web services `war`. My project structure is like this

```
workspace/commons/projecta with gradle.build
workspace/commons/projectb with gradle.build
workspace/commons/projectc with gradle.build 
workspace/war/restapi with gradle.build
```

Now I have 2 choices, create a shell script in use a shell script OR to use gradle dependencies. But the documentation link above, does not mention how to specify dependencies `../commons/projectc`. The syntax seems to be only forward looking. Seems like I must create a `build.gradle` in workspace.

Comment: How does your `settings.gradle` look? You can add a gradle project at any arbitrary path as a subproject to your settings.gradle. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19303545/745574) for an example. You do not need a build.gradle in workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Gradle.build file is an easy way to handle your problem.

A syntax example:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.shiro:shiro-core:1.2.3'
}
```

In the example above I add the Shiro-Core to my dependencies.

Try the following link [Dependency Management Basics](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html).

Comment: But my project structure is different,  how will gradle know to ../../projectb ?

Comment: Please note, I am not asking for "external" dependencies that are in repositories.. I am asking for local project dependencies.