# Multiple project Gradle builds with non-standard folder hierarchy

Tags: gradle, build, multi-project

Typically, a multi project Gradle build would be setup something like this:

```
root
   subproject1
   subproject2
```

And in `root`'s `settings.gradle` file, I'd have something like:

```
rootProject.name = 'root'
include 'subproject1'
include 'subproject2'
```

This kind of multi-project setup is straightforward. However, what if `subproject1` or `subproject2` aren't contained within `root`? For example, I might have an existing subproject on my machine that is stored somewhere far away from `root`. How do I configure the `setting.gradle` file to account for this "non-standard" structure? Is it just a matter of providing an absolute path to the `subproject` folder in the `settings.gradle` file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Require Gradle project from another directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299316/require-gradle-project-from-another-directory)

Answer (score 0):

This post covers it: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-include-sub-projects-in-settings-gradle-file/5096

Basically, you have to overwrite the `project.projectDir` attribute of your subproject so that it points to the location of the subproject on your machine.