# Grails 3 (Gradle) dependency without parent directory

Tags: gradle, dependencies, grails-3.3

Can I not use the following Gradle approach to dependencies in Grails? I do not have nor want a parent directory;
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19303545/2288004

When I try it, I get the the following error;

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected method not found:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.addApplicationListener(org.apache.catalina.deploy.ApplicationListener)

It works when I use a parent directory for the settings.gradle, but unfortunately it’s not how I want to structure the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following was indeed the solution I was looking for,

```
include ":myplugin"
project(':myplugin').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../myplugin')
```

The error was down to how I was managing my tomcat dependencies between the two projects.

Tomcat was already being pulled in via the plugin but while I still needed to reference tomcat at compile time in the application, I also needed to make sure it was the same version, and so added the following just above "dependencies" to target the version I required;

```
ext['tomcat.version'] = '7.0.70'
```