# Android Studio: Declaring Gradle Dependencies

Tags: gradle, android-studio, dependencies, build.gradle

I'm trying to declare my own custom libraries as dependencies in Gradle. I need to declare that 'Project A' is dependent and must compile 'Project B'.

The 'settings.gradle' file for Project A (which includes Project B: mylibrary) would look like this:

```
include ':app', ':mylibrary'

project(':mylibrary').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../mylibrary/lib')
```

And I'd make sure that 'build.gradle' had:

```
compile project(':mylibrary')
```

Previously, I had **ALL** my Android Studio Projects in '~/AndroidStudioProjects' (I develop on a Mac). However, I  have done some "*organising*" of my file structure. 'Project A', which uses and relies on classes/methods from 'Project B' (i.e. 'mylibrary'), are no longer in the same, base, root directory (previously ~/AndroidStudioProjects; my projects now reside in different directories).

How do I declare a project location in Gradle that is an outside project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot. Gradle provides [two methods to include](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings.html) projects to multi-project build. These are

- include(projectPaths)
- includeFlat(projectNames)

include expect that your projects has common root directory, like below, and you use this command in Root directory settings.gradle

```
ProjectMain
  ProjectA
  ProjectB
```

includeFlat expect that your projects reside in same directory, but you use this command in one of the child directories' settings.gradle. [Good example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995390/gradle-how-to-configure-multiproject-setup-with-side-by-side-projects).

```
ProjectMain
ProjectA
ProjectB
```

If you made some arrangements for directories, best choice for you to use [symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) approach.

Comment: What's the proper way then to go about including libraries? With my previous methods, I could make a change in the library, and it would be reflected throughout any project that uses the library. I do not want to have to compile and recompile and include my library as a separate .jar file every time.

Comment: @user1234 that means including your library projects as symbolic link in main project.