# How to build multi flat dir without root dir using Gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I'm trying to build multi project with flat style.

Expected result is that `gradle build` under `baseproj` directory compile and build using `libsproj` directory's libraries.

This is my directory structure.

```
workspace
├── baseproj
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── settings.gradle
│   └── src/main/java/sample.java
└── libsproj
    ├── batch
    │   ├── foo.jar
    │   └── some.jar
    └── web
        ├── hoge.jar
        └── some.jar
```

Here is my **`build.gradle`**:

```
apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "application"

jar.baseName = 'base'
version = ''
def mainClass = 'sample'
mainClassName =  mainClass

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

project(':libsproj') {
  dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: "${projectDir}/libs", include: '*.jar')
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile project ':libsproj'
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

and here is **`setting.gradle`**:

```
rootProject.name = 'baseproj'
rootProject.projectDir = new File(settingsDir, 'baseproj')
includeFlat 'libsproj'
```

and also this is **`gradle projects`** output:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

Root project 'baseproj'
\--- Project ':libsproj'
```

If I run **`gradle build`**, it says just successful, but it did not build my Java file.

```
:buildEnvironment

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

classpath
No dependencies

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

I understand if I create `settings.gradle` under the root dir (i.e. `workspace` dir in this example.), but this directory structure will be like the following:

```
├── anotherproj
├── baseproj
├── libsproj
│   ├── batch
│   └── web
└── otherproj
```

`otherproj` needs `libsproj`, and `anotherproj` needs `libsproj` and `baseproj`, and so on.

At this time, I can workaround with `fileTree` in `build.gradle` like the following:

```
compile fileTree(dir: "../libsproj/batch", include: '*.jar')
```

But, it will be stuck when some other project is added. (e.g. `otherproj` on the above)

So, how can I build with multi flat directory.
Do you have any ideas? Please give me a hand.

FYI: Before post this question, I checked these questions.

- [Having difficulty setting up Gradle multiproject build for existing repository layout - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14729072/having-difficulty-setting-up-gradle-multiproject-build-for-existing-repository-l)
- [java - Gradle: How to configure multiproject setup with side-by-side projects - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995390/gradle-how-to-configure-multiproject-setup-with-side-by-side-projects)
- [rtc - How to do a Gradle setup for flat projects with no physical root - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19387842/how-to-do-a-gradle-setup-for-flat-projects-with-no-physical-root)

Answer (score 1):

From my practice it's very useful to have a separate repository for each Gradle build.

But for your specific case you can just fix `include` wildcard expression:

```
compile fileTree(dir: "${projectDir}/libs", include: '**/*.jar')
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. First of all, I agree with your comment about repository separation. I often do so in my personal project.

Comment: Your `include: '**/*.jar'` is very great if I could do that on the workspace directory on the above example. Maybe my question is ambiguous, but I must do that on `otherproj` or `anotherproj` or so. Anyway, if I did it with like the following: `include: '../**/*.jar', exclude: otherproj`, it will be the one of alternative solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

Add this into your *workspace/buildproj/settings.gradle* file

```
 includeBuild '../libsproj/web'
```

Had a similar issue - as it looks that works for me - it brings some MultiRepo convenience into the gradle world.